# How to forecast revenue when there is little data available?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series, data-science, arima

I have quarterly revenues of an organisation from 2014 third quarter till 2017 second quarter, how to forecast revenue for 2018 quarters having this much data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this little data, it will be hard to fit a time series model. If you are able to get more data (more frequent), time series analysis may work.

If you cannot, I would try to obtain other data that may be related to the revenues (eg marketing campaigns budget of each quarter etc) and use a simple statistical model like a linear regression or a decision tree.

If you really cannot obtain more data, try to visualize the data to see if there is a trend over the years and whether there is a seasonality. Then try to fit a linear model with variables 'quarter' (if you see seasonality) and 'year' (if you see a trend over the years).

Comment: the last point probably is the most feasible and practical thing to do.